# Pandas: Sum of two boolean series

Tags: python, pandas

In Python:

```
In [1]: True+True
Out[1]: 2
```

So after the following set-up:

```
import pandas as pd
ser1 = pd.Series([True,True,False,False])
ser2 = pd.Series([True,False,True,False])
```

What I want is to find the element-wise sum of `ser1` and `ser2`, with the booleans treated as integers for addition as in the Python example.

But Pandas treats the addition as an element-wise "or" operator, and gives the following (undesired) output:

```
In [5]: ser1+ser2
*/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/expressions.py:184: UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '+' operator is not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '|' instead
  unsupported[op_str]))
Out[5]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

I know I get can get my **desired** output using `astype(int)` on either series:

```
In [6]: ser1.astype(int) + ser2
Out[6]: 
0    2
1    1
2    1
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Is there another (more "pandonic") way to get the [2,1,1,0] series? Is there a good explanation for why simple Series addition doesn't work here?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: if you want to treat a boolean Series as if the elements were ints and not bools, calling `astype(int)` sounds as pandorable as it gets.  What kind of explanation are you looking for?

Comment: Right, I see that it works. My question is more about *why* the pandas `+` operation on Series does not give the same result as the element-wise python `+` operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, what you're looking for is that the operative convention is that of numpy bool arrays, not Python bools:

```
>>> a = True
>>> a+a
2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([a])
array([ True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.array([a]) + np.array([a])
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

Could've gone either way, and if memory serves at least one pandas dev was surprised by this behaviour, but doing it this way matches the idea that Series are typed.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I was looking for. Though I guess this pushes the question one level deeper -- do you know why this is the convention in numpy?

Comment: @exp1orer '+' is de-facto '&' and '-' is '|' for these elemenwise aggregations of boolean ops. As the sum of ``True`` and ``True`` is really undefined. So one could argue that python is really doing an un-pythonic operation (it is actually coercing to int first). But forced coercion is normally NOT done in numpy/pandas. Its unpythonic IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `+` use `&`

```
import pandas as pd
ser1 = pd.Series([True,True,False,False])
ser2 = pd.Series([True,False,True,False]) 

print(ser1 & ser2) 

>> 0     True
>> 1    False
>> 2    False
>> 3    False
>> dtype: bool
```